# Restart from certain point in java

Tags: java

My problem regards loops and exceptions. If i run this programma it will take me to point 1, but it only let's me put in a string and then just stops. Whereas I want it to continue, just as it initially did. What am I doing wrong?

```
    while (true) {
        try {
    //From here I want to start everytime. Point 1
            System.out.println("Do you whish to deposit or withdraw money or end the transaction?");
            Scanner readerBankTransactions = new Scanner(System.in);
            String BankTransaction = readerBankTransactions.nextLine();

            if (BankTransaction.equalsIgnoreCase(Transactions.ENDTRANSACTION.toString())) {
                System.out.println("Thank you for using our service.");
                break; //The programma should terminate here

            } else {
                while (true) {
                    if (BankTransaction.equalsIgnoreCase(Transactions.DEPOSIT.toString())) {
                        System.out.println("How much do you whish to deposit?");
                        Scanner readerDeposit = new Scanner(System.in);
                        double deposit = readerDeposit.nextDouble();
                        rekening.deposit(deposit);
                        double balance = rekening.getBalance();
                        System.out.println("Your balance is now: " + balance);
                        readerDeposit.close();
                        break; //from here I want to start again at point 1.

                    } else if (BankTransaction.equalsIgnoreCase(Transactions.WITHDRAW.toString())) {
                        System.out.println("How much do you whish to withdraw?");
                        Scanner readerWithdraw = new Scanner(System.in);
                        double withdraw = readerWithdraw.nextDouble();
                        rekening.withdraw(withdraw);
                        double balance = rekening.getBalance();
                        System.out.println("Your balance is now: " + balance);
                        readerWithdraw.close();
                        break; //from here I want to start again at point 1.
                    } 
                    readerBankTransactions.close();
                    readerbankAccountNumber.close();
                }
            } continue;
        } catch (InputMismatchException | NumberFormatException exception1) {
            System.out.println("This is not what you should have put in");
        } catch (InsufficientFundsException exception2) {
            System.out.println("insufficientfunds!");
        } catch (MaximumWithdrawException exception3) {
            System.out.println("Maximum withdraw restriction!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be great if you could be more particular about where exactly your issue is and what exactly you are trying to achieve. You may also have a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to improve the question. Welcome to SO!

Comment: Generally speaking..just bad code and doesn't make sense. So, either be very clear in your question and objective or...good luck.

Comment: Do you know where it's stopping?  If not, use print statements or something functionally similar to determine where the problem is.  Is it the nextLine() statement, by any chance?

Comment: Thank a lot for the feedback! Yesterday I went on working with this programma, but in the end I got so much while and if statements that I completely lost the overal picture. So I started again and used a switch statement, which worked a lot better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some suggestions:

- Try to avoid the pattern of `while (true)` followed by `continue` or `break` statements. It makes the logic very hard to follow.
- You should isolate some of the logic in helper methods. Again, this will make the main logic easier to follow.
- I don't understand the purpose of the inner `while` loop. What are you trying to accomplish here?

With that, here's my suggested rewrite:

```
do {
    try {
        String BankTransaction = getInitialSelection();

        if (isDepositRequest(BankTransaction)) {
            handleDeposit();
        } else if (isWithdrawalRequest(BankTransaction)) {
            handleWithdrawal();
        } 
    } catch (InputMismatchException | NumberFormatException exception1) {
        System.out.println("This is not what you should have put in");
    } catch (InsufficientFundsException exception2) {
        System.out.println("insufficientfunds!");
    } catch (MaximumWithdrawException exception3) {
        System.out.println("Maximum withdraw restriction!");
    }
} while (!isExitRequest(BankTransaction));
System.out.println("Thank you for using our service.");
```

This is assuming definitions of `handleDeposit()`, `handleWithdrawal()` matching the corresponding code in your original code.

Also, I've assumed the following helper methods:

```
private boolean isDepositRequest(String bankTransaction) {
    return Transactions.DEPOSIT.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(bankTransaction);
}

private boolean isWithdrawalRequest(String bankTransaction) {
    return Transactions.WITHDRAW.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(bankTransaction);
}

private boolean isExitRequest(String bankTransaction) {
    return Transactions.ENDTRANSACTION.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(bankTransaction);
}
```

Comment: This seems like a much better solution. I tried to work with this but it gives me an error in the while loop. It states that I have not yet declared a variable named BankTransaction. I quess that this is because I initialize I within the try statement? I don't know how to solve this

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called a labelled break. Take a look information on labelled breaks  at : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html
Use a label for your outer while loop for eg `point1 :` and in the place where you want to restart from point 1 use `break point1;`

Comment: Thanks! This helped a lot when recreating my programma witch a switch statement.